# How to sum three or more tables with same columns in SQL in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please see below address and see the solution

[How to sum two tables with same columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618783/how-to-sum-two-tables-with-same-columns/77630457?noredirect=1#comment136858982_77630457)

Please tell me how I can sum three or more tables. Thank you all

```
SELECT 
    material, SUM(table1_sale), SUM(table2_Sale)
FROM
    (SELECT
         material, SUM(sale) AS table1_sale, 0 as table2_sale 
     FROM
         table1 
     GROUP BY
         material
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         material, 0, SUM(sale) 
     FROM
         table2 
     GROUP BY
         material) x
GROUP BY 
    material
ORDER BY 
    material;
```

I have used this solution for two tables.

Comment: Can UNION up to 50 tables.

Comment: would you please write the code according to above code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618783/how-to-sum-two-tables-with-same-columns/77630457?noredirect=1#comment136858982_77630457

Comment: Why can't you just use the two SELECT lines you have as template to include a third table? Add another field to the two existing SELECT lines and build a 3rd SELECT to conform.

Comment: i did this but i got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your data with multiple `UNION ALL`, add a source column, and then use conditional aggregations with `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`.

```
SELECT 
    material, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table1', sale, 0)) AS table1_sale, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table2', sale, 0)) AS table2_sale,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table3', sale, 0)) AS table3_sale
FROM
    (SELECT material, sale, 'table1' AS source 
     FROM table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT material, sale, 'table2'
     FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT material, sale, 'table3'
     FROM table3) x
GROUP BY 
    material
ORDER BY 
    material;
```

[Demo on sql server](https://dbfiddle.uk/xt1XoaoL)

Comment: i think this code do diferent work i want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618783/how-to-sum-two-tables-with-same-columns/77630457?noredirect=1#comment136858982_77630457          but with same as link

Comment: whit this code i got Error : Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'sum ( case when source = 'table1' then sale else 0 end) .... in microsoft access

Comment: I have edited my answer to use `IIF` an equivalent of `CASE` clause